# Find group of records that match multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

```
ID --- ParentID --- DataValue  
1  ---    1     ---    1  
2  ---    1     ---    2  
3  ---    1     ---    6  
4  ---    2     ---    1  
5  ---    2     ---    2  
6  ---    2     ---    4  
7  ---    3     ---    1  
8  ---    3     ---    3  
9  ---    3     ---    5
```

For each group of records (grouped by ParentID), I would like to find all groups that match all given values in DataValue, for example:

- for values (1,2) ParentID 1 and 2 would be returned
- for values (1,6) only ParentID 1 would be returned (ParentID 2 group doesn't contain 6)

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147505/find-group-of-records-that-match-a-certain-criteria), which is very similar but OP looks for groups that do not contain single value.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select parentid 
from tablename
group by parentid
having sum(case when datavalue = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when datavalue = 6 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Another way is use `exists`:

```
select distinct parentid
from tablename t1
where exists(select * from tablename where parentid = t1.parentid and datavalue = 1) and
      exists(select * from tablename where parentid = t1.parentid and datavalue = 6)
```

Another way is counting distinct occurrences:

```
select parentid 
from tablename
where datavalue in(1, 6)
group by parentid
having count(distinct datavalue) = 2
```